# spring batch - command line execution

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have done the following downloaded sample spring batch project in to spring tool suite and followed the steps listed in the example .

I was able to run the application inside the STS . but when i create the jar file using maven build --> clean install and try to execute the command 
I'm not that clear with the command to execute few options i used 
java -jar name.jar 
java  -jar name.jar  classpath:/launch-context.xml  firstJob
java org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.commandlinejobrunner classpath:/launch-context.xml  firstJob

the error is could not find or load main class org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.commandlinejobrunner

I would appreciate any help on this . thanks

Answer (score 0):

which application have you downloaded and tried to execute? usually to run a jar : java -jar jar-file
Before you execute this command, make sure that the runtime environment has information about which class within the JAR file is the application's entry point.

To indicate which class is the application's entry point, you must add a Main-Class header to the JAR file's manifest. The header takes the form:

Main-Class: classname

The header's value, classname, is the name of the class that is the application's entry point.

Please see - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

Comment: Based on what i have read so far , after developing   the project  have to run maven build -- clean install . maven creates a .jar file and have to run that jar file .